# Cannot create a file when that file already exists on rebuilding project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I'm testing OneSignal in my Xamarin.Forms project, First time when I create my project and add OneSignal nuget package to it everything is ok and I can run and build my project but when I close and reopen Visual Studio it seems my project is broken and not build anymore: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Is anyone know what should I Do?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Clearing all nuget caches, Opening project directory and manually delete obj and bin folders , But none of them working ..

Comment: We more information than "broken and not build anymore" lets see some console log errors, what's exactly failing, what build process is failing, did you try manually delete your bin and obj folders ?

Comment: Did you try running Visual Studio with Administrator privileges (Run as Administrator)?

Comment: I always run visual studio with administrator privileges and yes, I  have deleted obj and bin folders manually but the error is still there, Even when I crate new xamarin forms project then add OneSignal nuget package, If I close the project or visual studio and reopen it, The project is not built anymore..

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after installing a Preview of Visual Studio. I resolve this by deleting all the files in
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch

Hope this helps you or someone else.